# Why am I unable to apply a border to an angular mat-table row?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a simple angular material table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="scoreboardData">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="totalScore">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total Score </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totalScore}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to add some extra margin between the rows as well as a border and maybe even some padding. I have found that I am able to change the background color of the rows, but I'm not able to apply margins, padding or borders to the row.

```
tr.mat-row {
    background: #2f5b98; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,144,239,1) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,144,239,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,144,239,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4a90ef', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #FAFF00;
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure out what is preventing me from applying these styles to the row. Again, I can change the background, the font within it and several other styles, just not these three particular styles (padding, margin, border).

EDIT: I have since determined that padding and margin are not allowed on any html tables. Border still eludes me though.

Comment: Try this .mat-table tr.mat-row

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, AnshulJS, but no luck there.

Comment: Put the style in your `styles.css` file, so that it isn't encapsulated.

Comment: Try to give your styles to td. It works. And you can use padding to make space rather than using margin.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your styling problems don't have to do with Angular Material tables but with HTML tables in general. If you search for how to style a `table` e.g. add borders to rows or margins you'll find various answers and suggestions.

**You basically can't add `margin` or `padding` to a table row `<tr>` directly.**

> **[`margin`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#propdef-margin)** applies to all elements except elements with table display types other than *table-caption*, *table* and *inline-table*.

> **[`padding`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#propdef-padding)** applies to all elements except *table-row-group*, *table-header-group*, *table-footer-group*, *table-row*, *table-column-group*
>   and table-column.

### Solutions

How you set a `border` for table rows and specify a `margin` and `padding` depends on the [border model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#borders) (`collapse` or `separate`) you use.

#### The separated borders model: `border-collapse: seperate`

> In the **separated borders model**, the edges coincide with
>   the border edges of cells. (And thus, in this model, there may be gaps
>   between the rows, columns, row groups or column groups, corresponding
>   to the 'border-spacing' property.)
>
> In this model, each cell has an individual border. The
>   'border-spacing' property specifies the distance between the borders
>   of adjoining cells. (...) Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups
>   cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border
>   properties for those elements).

**1. Solution:** If you want a **border**, **margin** and **padding** you could do something like this:

```css
td.mat-cell {
 /* row padding */
 padding: 16px 0;
 /* row border */
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffa600;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffa600;
}

td.mat-cell:first-child {
  /* row border */
  border-left: 1px solid #ffa600;
}

td.mat-cell:last-child {
  /* row border */
  border-right: 1px solid #ffa600;
}

table {
  /* row spacing / margin */
  border-spacing: 0 8px !important;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-wtkfg4

#### The collapsing border model: `border-collapse: collapse`

> The edges of the rows, columns, row groups and column groups in the
>   **collapsing borders model** coincide with the hypothetical grid lines on
>   which the borders of the cells are centered. (And thus, in this model,
>   the rows together exactly cover the table, leaving no gaps; ditto for
>   the columns.)
>
> In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that
>   surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column
>   group. (...) Also, in this model, a table does not have padding (but does have margins).

**2. Solution:** If you only want a row **border** and **padding** but no spacing / margin between the rows you could do:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  /* row border */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffa600;
}

td.mat-cell {
  /* row padding */
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: none;
}

tr.mat-row {
  /* row border */
  border: 1px solid #ffa600;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-xphbue

Answer (score 2):

```css
mat-footer-row, mat-header-row, mat-row {
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
}
```

try this code. This will work :)

Answer (score -1):

```
.mat-cell {
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}

.mat-cell:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}

.mat-row:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}

.mat-row:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}
.mat-column {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}
.mat-column:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}
.mat-header-cell:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}
.mat-header-cell {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(97 82 82);
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0 8px !important;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

The simplest and better way is to utilize the power of angular material.
Use mat-table, mat-header-cell, mat-cell instead of table, th, td. At the end use mat-header row and mat-row instead of th and td.  Then you can border each row as you want.

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-border)

Comment: How to add the boundary to the columns?

Comment: @MdRafee - the neg from me. why don't you give us working example for the footer for example.